# Why does "reduce" not reduce in jq

Tags: jq

#### tl;dr

In the language of `jq`, why is

```
$ jq --compact-output reduce (1,2,3,4) as $i ([]; . + [$i])
[1,2,3,4]
```

not the same as

```
$ jq --compact-output (1,2,3,4) | reduce . as $i ([]; . + [$i])
[1]
[2]
[3]
[4]
```

#### Full question and discussion

I have a somewhat theoretical question in that I have figured out a way to get the transformation I want, but still I do not understand completely why my first attempt failed and I would like an explanation.

Interactive example at [jqPlay](https://jqplay.org/s/N0eE52b3c_)

I have input

```
{
  "data": {
    "k1": "v1"
  },
  "item": {
    "data": {
      "k2": "v2"
    }
  }, 
  "list": {
    "item": {
      "data": {
        "k3": "v3",
        "k4": "v4"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I want to collect into a single array all of the values of all of the keys that are immediate children of a "data" key. So the output I want is

```
["v1","v2","v3","v4"]
```

I eventually figured out that this works

```
jq --compact-output '[.. | .data? | select(.) | to_entries | .[].value]'
```

My question is, why could I not get it to work with `reduce`? I originally tried

```
.. | .data? | select(.) | to_entries | .[].value | reduce . as $v ([]; . + [$v])
```

but that gave me

```
["v1"]
["v2"]
["v3"]
["v4"]
```

instead. My question is why? `reduce` is supposed to iterate over multiple values, but what kind of multiple values does it iterate over and what kind are treated as separate inputs to separate `reduce` statements?

I guess my fundamental confusion is when is `.` (dot) an expression with 4 results and when is it 4 expressions? Or if `.` is always a an expression with 1 result, how do you collect 4 results back into 1, which is what `reduce` is all about? Is the array operator the only way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An expression of the form:

```
reduce STREAM as ...
```

reduces the given stream, whereas the compound expression:

```
STREAM | reduce . as ...
```

invokes `reduce` once for each item in the stream, and for each invocation, `.` is that item.

---

If the concept of streams is unclear in this context, you might be interested to read a stream-oriented introduction to jq that I wrote:
https://github.com/pkoppstein/jq/wiki/A-Stream-oriented-Introduction-to-jq

Comment: Would you kindly explain what `jq` filters combine arbitrary numbers of streams back into a single one and give an example or two. I understand that `[ multiple-streams ]` produces an single stream with an array containing the outputs of the multiple streams, but is there a way to do that on the right side of a pipe? `.[] | [.]` does not produce the original array. Is there any inverse to `.[]`?

Comment: For external streams, you can use the -s command-line option; for an internal stream, say STREAM, you can use `[STREAM]`, `reduce STREAM ...`, `foreach STREAM ...`, or write your own def with STREAM as an argument, e.g. `def myaggregator(STREAM)`. For further details and examples, please see the stream-oriented introduction that I've already cited.

Comment: The missing manual! Thank you so much for publishing your stream-oriented introduction.

Comment: Can you please provide more detail on the solution for internal streams? I don't know what `reduce STREAM` means. I accept that `-` refers to each item in an input stream instead of the whole stream. So how do I refer to the whole stream?

Comment: I used `reduce (inputs | item_filter) ...` to get what I needed. Previously I used `item_filter | reduce . ...` as the OP did and had the same problem. Is that really the only way to do it?

Comment: You can refer to an entire stream as such in `reduce` and `foreach` expressions, and also as arguments to defined functions.  To capture a stream, say STREAM, as an array: [STREAM]